# What bus operator is "NYP"?

Tags: buses, greyhound

In [Greyhound schedule 742](http://extranet.greyhound.com/Revsup/csked/pdf/742.pdf), there are buses by *GLI*, *ADT*, and *NYP*.  *GLI* is *Greyhound LInes*, *ADT* is *Adirondack Trailways*, but what does NYP stand for?  It's the code for the Amtrak New York Penn station but that doesn't seem related.  Is it *New York Trailways*?  But then what's the *P* for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually NYP = [Pine Hill Trailways](http://trailwaysny.com/).  Pine Hill along with Adirondack and New York Trailways operate under the same umbrella of *New York Trailways*, hence NYP(New York Pine Hill).